# Firebase, Ember and Emberfire create user

Tags: ember.js, firebase

Firebase offers some easy ways to [create users](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html):

I'm currently using EmberFire (Add-on) with Firebase, and I'm wondering how this would translate to use in Ember:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.createUser({
  email: "bobtony@firebase.com",
  password: "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
        console.log("The new user account cannot be created because the email is already in use.");
        break;
      case "INVALID_EMAIL":
        console.log("The specified email is not a valid email.");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
  }
});
```

So you can then create a user, save it to Ember Data and also save it in Firebase?  There are also other methods changeEmail(), changePassword() etc... so I'm simply looking for an example to apply this to Emberfire ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the Firebase Team, here is the solution:

In your controller/mixin/component, you would defined your firebase connection, and then in your actions, you can use firebase code as shown in their docs with some minor edits:

```
{
    firebase: Ember.inject.service(),
    actions: {
        submission: function(){
            const ref = this.get('firebase');
            ref.createUser({
                email: this.get('email'),
                password: this.get('password')
            }, function(error, userData) {

            if (error) {

                switch (error.code) {

                    case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
                        console.log('user already exists');
                    break;
                    case "INVALID_EMAIL":
                        console.log('your email looks wrong');
                    break;
                    case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                        console.log('your password looks incorrect');
                    break;
                    default:
                        console.log(error.message);

                }

            } else {

                console.log('record added!');
                console.log(userData);

            }


            });

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @SuperUberDuper which version of ember and firebase are you using?

Comment: _firebase.default.auth.createUser is undef. I'm using **"firebase": "^4.1.3",** and importing via: `import firebase from 'firebase'`

Comment: This post was for an older version of firebase/ember.  I would recommend following this guide: https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md and this:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth  let me know if you need more direction.

Comment: in the end I had to use firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),